# Cant get JS validation to respond

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I'm trying to get validation to work when pressing submit, but no alerts pop up when submit is pressed, where I should get an alert that field is empty and such. Can anyone spot an error in my code? As I can't quite grasp what's the error, tried doing validation line by line as well.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["comment"].value;
  if (x == "" && y == "") {
    alert("Please enter the blank fields!");
return false;
   } else if (x == "") {
    alert("Please enter your name!");
    return false;
   } else if (y == "") {
    alert("Please leave us a comment!");
    return false;
   } else {
     if(document.getElementById('r5').checked) {
       window.alert("Thank you")
      }
   }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper * {
  float: right;
}

.wrapper input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  font-size: 30px;
}

input:checked ~ label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<link REL="StyleSheet"  TYPE="text/css" HREF="example2.css">

<body>

  <form id ="myForm">
    Name: <input type="text" id="fname">
    <br><br>
    Comment: <input type="input" id="comment">
    <br><br>
 


    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rg1">
      <label for="r1">&#10038;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rg1">
      <label for="r2">&#10038;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rg1">
      <label for="r3">&#10038;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="r4" name="rg1">
      <label for="r4">&#10038;</label>
      <input type="radio" id="r5" name="rg1">
      <label for="r5">&#10038;</label>
    </div>
 <br>

<button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm"()>Submit </button>
  </form>
  
</body>
<script src="jsreview.js"></script>
</html>
```

Thank you for checking this

Comment: You don't seem to be call your form validation code from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an id to your form and submit button as below.

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

also, add below line in your javascript file

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', validateForm);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, however, it's still the same and submit won't show any errors

Comment: Thank you, now it alerts whenever name + comment is not filled in, however, when submitted with r5(5 stars) it won't show any alerts.

Comment: You have to change the coding for the star in HTML as well as in Js.

Answer (score 0):

First your not link submit and js function
And submit button sometimes goes default form submition ,so use button type instead of submit

Set alert() in first line of function ,so you can easily check it

`<input type=button" value= SUBMIT" onclick="validateform()" >`

**or**

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

`<script>`
`function myFunction() {`
 `alert( "Hello World");`
`}
</script>`

Comment: Updated it, however it's the same and does not respond to submit

Comment: Look into browser console for any syntax error message. Comment all code inside function and set only one alert to check button control come into function... Answer updated

Comment: Thank you, the button works correctly now if comment or name fields are not filled out, however when 5 stars selected, alert with "Thank you" Won't show up